# Undefined variable when calling an id from api

Tags: php, function, api, url

I'm working on a PHP project the teacher gave us, basically we have to make a website dynamic and create a liste.php with tasks stored in an API the teacher has.

So I have the index.php with the front page on it and the list of all the projects going on ( like trip preparation, shopping list and appartment decoration ). I created a liste.php with all the tasks contained in each project ( buying tickets, booking the hotel and buying a postcard for the trip preparation ).

Now I have to get all the tasks of each project from the API he gave us.

Here's the API

http://todo_api.xx.firstname-lastname.com/tache.php?liste_id=1

That's the API for project n°1, there are 3 projects in total ( I mentionned them all above )

I also have a functions.php with the $api_url stored, and 2 functions, one getting the list of projects, the other getting the tasks for each project.

```
$api_url = "http://todo_api.xx.firstname-lastname.com/";


function getAllListes(): array {
    global $api_url;

    $json = file_get_contents($api_url . "liste.php");
    return json_decode($json, true);
}



function getAllTaches(): array {
    global $api_url;
    $json = file_get_contents($api_url . "tache.php?liste_id=" . $id);
    return json_decode($json, true);
}
```

But when I try to print_r that, or even just display each task, I get this :

Notice: Undefined index: liste_id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/todo/database/functions.php on line 17

So obviously something is wrong, and this keeps me from going on. Any idea ?

Edit : here's my html/php code regarding the tasklist

```
$listes = getAllListes();
$taches = getAllTaches($id);

<ul>

        <?php foreach ($taches as $tache) : ?>
        <li><?php echo $tache["libelle"] ;?></li>
        <?php endforeach ; ?>
    </ul>
```

libelle is the index of the information required.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Looks like your teacher forgot to run some `$_GET` checks. You're getting that issue because `$id` in `getAllTaches` is not getting set.

Comment: Yep I noticed that, I forgot to write " int $id " as a parameter for the functions.

Comment: So does it work now that you have done that?

Comment: So the error disappeared, but now the array won't display anything, the print_r displays array(), and the foreach displays no <li> at all.

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Sounds like either the call to tache.php returned no results, or it failed somehow. You'll have to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in functions.php

```
function getAllTaches(): array { //declared function without parameter
```

but html/php code

```
$taches = getAllTaches($id);// calling the function with parameter.
```

i guess if you pass the parameter to the function it will work.

Comment: Yep I figured this one and changed it, so the error doesn't appear anymore. Now the array won't display anything, the print_r displays array(), and the foreach displays no <li> at all. Thanks !